Exercise on induced characters
I was studying representation theory when a question came to my mind.
I am having troubles in solving the following exercise. 
Given two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$ such that $G=HK$, let $L=H \cap K$; in addition, given a character $f$ of $H$, write $f_X$ for restriction to a subgroup $X$ and $f^X$ for the induced character to $X$. Show that $(f^G)_K = (f_L)^K$.
After carefully writing down the definitions I don't know how to go on. This exercise appears also in Isaacs' "Character Theory of Finite Groups" (Problem 5.2), under hypothesis that $f$ is a class function of $H$ (not necessarily a character).

Class functions are linear combinations of characters and both sides of this identity are linear in $f$, so statements of this form are true for characters iff they're true for class functions.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you for pointing it out.

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

@Shaun Thank you, although right now I’d need more something like a representation theory tutorial.

Let $T=\{t_1,\ldots,t_n\}$ be a right transversal of $H\cap K$ in $K$. Let's see that $T$ is also a right transversal of $H$ in $G$. If $g\in G$ then there exist $h\in H,k\in K$ such that $g=hk$. Writing $k=st_i$ for some $s\in H\cap K$ it follows that $g\in Ht_i$. Now, if there is $t_j\in Ht_i$ we may write $t_j=ht_i$ for some $h\in H$ and hence $h=t_jt_i^{-1}\in H\cap K$. Since $t_j\in (H\cap K)t_i$ then $t_j=t_i$ and $T$ is a right transversal of $H$ in $G$.
Let $k\in K$. For each $t\in T$ it holds $tkt^{-1}\in H$ if and only if $tkt^{-1}\in H\cap K$. Then
\begin{equation*}
    (f^G)_K(k)=\sum_{t\in T}\dot f(tkt^{-1})=\sum_{t\in T}\dot{ f_{H\cap K}}(tkt^{-1})=(f_{H\cap K})^K(k),
\end{equation*}
and we are done.
